# null value in HttpPostedFileBase [same name, correct enctype in a partialview shown in modal pop up]

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, file-upload

Partial view opened in a modal

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Line", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
  @Html.AntiForgeryToken()    
  @Html.LabelFor(model => model.U_Attachment, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
  @Html.EditorFor(model => model.U_Attachment, new { htmlAttributes = new { @type = "file" } })
  @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.U_Attachment, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
}
```

Action

```
 [HttpPost]
 [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
 public ActionResult Create(LINE model, HttpPostedFileBase U_Attachment)
{   
    //value is null for U_Attachment
}
```

I confirmed that the enctype is correct, method is post and the names are correct. what else is missing here?

**Update**: To load pop up modal, i am using the following script. This script will reload a div with the result url. Is this the issue?

```
**

**$(function () {
        $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });
        $("a[data-modal]").on("click", function (e) {               
            $('#myModalContent').load(this.href, function () {
                $('#myModal').modal({
                    /*backdrop: 'static',*/
                    keyboard: true
                }, 'show');
                bindForm(this);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });
    function bindForm(dialog) {
        $('form', dialog).submit(function () {            
            $.ajax({
                url: this.action,
                type: this.method,
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function (result) {
                    if (result.success) {
                        $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                        $('#replacetarget').load(result.url); //  Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element
                    } else {
                        $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                        bindForm(dialog);
                    }
                }
            });
            return false;
        });
    }      
    </script>**
```

Comment: can you check in `Request.Files` ?

Comment: yea, Dont have too.

Comment: Is U_Attachment included within C_SI7_WEBPRLINE model and, if so, correctly referenced in the Action? Also, it'd be worth checking whether the modal creates a "form within a form"?

Comment: U_Attachment is there in C_SI7_WEBPRLINE. I checked the HTML generated, which have correct name too.

Comment: @Hybridzz if the file is in the C_SI7_WEBPRLINE model, shouldn't you reference that in the Action with var file = model.U_Attachment and remove HttpPostedFileBase U_Attachment in the Action parameters?

Comment: Using `.serialize()` does not work for file inputs. You can use `FormData` to upload files with ajax. Refer [How to append whole set of model to formdata and obtain it in MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681)

Answer (score 0):

1.if you wana send your form data with a file in ajax mode to server you should use ajaxForm library
so you should refrence the ajaxForm.js Library to your cshtml page

```
$('form').ajaxForm();
```

please write `$('form').ajaxForm();` before the main function of jquery
for example

```
<script>
 $('form').ajaxForm();
$(function(){
//write your normal code
});
</script>
```

2.script code can not work in partial view
so move your js script to a mainPage that is the parent of this partial view

Comment: after refrencing the ajaxForm library  in to your page you should add   $('form').ajaxForm(); to your code

Answer (score 0):

Uploading a file using ajax needs:

```
dataType: "json",
processData: false,
contentType: false,
```

as part of the $.ajax constructor.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution that worked for me (i got the same issue before):

```
- use normal html file input not using html helper AND add ATTRIBUTE "name"

<input type="file" id="U_Attachment" name="U_Attachment" />

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(LINE model, HttpPostedFileBase U_Attachment)
{   
    //value is null for U_Attachment
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@stephen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29293637/how-to-append-whole-set-of-model-to-formdata-and-obtain-it-in-mvc/29293681#29293681) helped me

To make things clearer,
I gave an ID for my form that is in the partial view

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "WebPRLine", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" , id = "CreateLine"}))
{
}
```

Then the Ajax call updated as below that sends the form data and the file

```
function bindForm(dialog) {
    $('form', dialog).submit(function () {           
        var formdata = new FormData($('#CreateLine').get(0));          
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            data: formdata,
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result.success) {
                    $('#myModal').modal('hide');
                    $('#replacetarget').load(result.url); //  Load data from the server and place the returned HTML into the matched element
                } else {
                    $('#myModalContent').html(result);
                    bindForm(dialog);
                }
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}
```

Thanks all. Cheers!